# Connecting Azure AD mobilePhone attribute to SharePoint Online/Delve

Tags: sharepoint, azure-active-directory, delve

I am running into an issue with having the user data for the mobilePhone attribute update and show up for our users' contact cards which run on the SPO/Delve platform. Does anyone know of a way to have the data sync?

Answer (score 0):

To update Azure AD mobile phone attribute to SharePoint online, try making use of below steps:

> Make sure to have the below modules installed before running the
> PowerShell script

- Azure Active Directory (AD) Module
- SharePoint Online Module
- MS Online Services Sign-in Assistant
- Office365 CSOM package

The user must be a **global admin** on the **SharePoint User Profile Application** as well as a **Service Admin** on the **Azure tenant**.

To connect to PowerShell, make sure the user account must not be configured to **MFA**.

To get all users, make use of below query,

```
$AzureADUsers = Get-MSolUser -All
```

To overwrite existing values, make use of below query,

```
$overwriteExistingSPOUPAValue = "True"
```

To know how to do it in detail, please find below **reference** by  Raymond Tishenko

[Sync Mobile Phone from Azure Active Directory to SharePoint Online using PowerShell (tishenko.com)](https://tishenko.com/sync-mobile-phone-from-aad-to-sharepoint-online/).

***After executing the script, you can see that values are successfully copied from Azure Active Directory to SharePoint.***